# Can not use android phone as emulator in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drivers

I've tried everything to make eclipse recognize my phone but it just wont. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 Skyrocket (I727) This is what I've tried

-Adding android:debuggable="true to the manifest
-Looking at["Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) on the google developers site.
 *But the thing is with that, is that when I try to install the USB Drivers from the \extras\google\usb_driver\ it says "Windows was unable to install your android" So I don't get why it's saying that. I've even tried installing the USB Drivers from samsungs website as well. If you could help me that'd be great. Thank You!

And yes, USB Debugging is enabled on my phone.

Solution: Installed Kies, rebooted. Ran kies. Then I went into settings on the phone. Storage, clicked the options button. Clicked USB computer connection, and selected Media Device (MTP) and it installed the drivers. And soon eclipse recognized it as well as kies.

Comment: is usb debugging turned on in your device settings?

Comment: Yes @FoamyGuy Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**
the drivers are not being installed successfully in your machine.

**Solution:**
kindly download and install Samsung Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP).It includes drivers for your Samsung device.

It will definitely solve your issue.

**Reference:**
[steps to follow while installing kies](http://skp.samsungcsportal.com/integrated/popup/FaqDetailPopup.jsp?seq=360772&cdsite=sg)

I hope it will be helpful !!

**EDIT:**

As suggested by `Fernando Ramirez`

In the cell-phone, Go to Settings -> Storage -> options -> USB computer connection -> select Media Device (MTP) and it will install the drivers

Comment: I downloaded Kies, and even updated it within the Kies application. But still the drivers are not installing. I did the troubleshooting guide within it and it tried to reinstall them again, but then it said Drivers not installed. Contact manufacturer for further help on installing the drivers

Comment: try to clean your registry before re-installing.it may solve the conflicts.

Comment: I tried cleaning it out, rebooted and nothing. Also tried uninstalling the drivers from the computer managament/devices/other/android part but then when I plug the phone back in and it tries to install them this always shows up http://tinypic.com/r/2w6xzdh/5

Comment: @FernandoRamirez: have a look at `http://skp.samsungcsportal.com/integrated/popup/FaqDetailPopup.jsp?seq=360772&cdsite=sg` and `http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/55647-device-driver-not-successfully-installed.html`

Comment: Actually I found a way to fix it. I went into settings on the phone. Storage, clicked the options button. Clicked USB computer connection, and selected Media Device (MTP) and it installed the drivers. And soon eclipse recognized it and now it's working! Thank You so much for your help, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: +1 for posting back the solution.I have updated answer so that it can help to others also in future :-)

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you want to debug your program directly from your phone. I had the same problem a while ago. I think if you install kias that can manage the installation of usb drivers. http://samsungcaptivate.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_USB_drivers_on_a_PC

Comment: I downloaded Kies, and even updated it within the Kies application. But still the drivers are not installing. I did the troubleshooting guide within it and it tried to reinstall them again, but then it said Drivers not installed. Contact manufacturer for further help on installing the drivers